# Google Charts: One set of bound controls --> two charts based on different datatables, via common column name/values

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Sorry if the title is a bit verbose, but the question I have is somewhat complicated.

I have two separate data tables (I'll call them `Data1` and `Data2`) and I'm trying to create a single set of Google Viz bound controls that will create a bar chart using `Data1` and a table using `Data2`. Because of the way I want the data presented and the lack of pivot table support in Google Charts, it doesn't make sense to combine them into a single dataset.

Normally I wouldn't think this would be possible, but in this case the two datasets share a column name populated with the same values. Based on other examples I've seen around here I think it should be possible to pick the control value using one dashboard and bind that control to a table in another dashboard, as long as the control's column title exists in both tables.

It's much easier to illustrate my problem than it is to explain it. Here's a [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qKGW2/3/), and here's the JavaScript:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});

function drawVisualization() {

// Prepare the data
var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'State', 'City', 'Value1','Value2','Sum'],
    ['USA' , 'New York', 'New York City', 15, 12, 27],
    ['USA', 'California', 'Los Angeles', 13, 7, 20],
    ['France', 'Provence', 'Marseilles', 16, 22, 38],
    ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Paris', 18, 42, 60]
]);

var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', 'InfoType','Value'],
    ['New York City','Addr','123 Broadway'],
    ['New York City','Owner1','John'],
    ['New York City','Owner2','Smith'],
    ['Los Angeles','Addr','789 Hollywood'],
    ['Los Angeles','Owner1','Jill'],
    ['Los Angeles','Owner2','White'],
    ['Marseilles','Addr','753 Magritte'],
    ['Marseilles','Owner1','Marie'],
    ['Marseilles','Owner2','Poitier'],
    ['Paris','Addr','869 Ave de Champs-Elysees'],
    ['Paris','Owner1','Albert'],
    ['Paris','Owner2','Gruyere']
]);     

// Define a category picker control for the Type column

var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control1',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Country',
        'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false,
            'allowNone': false
        }
    },
    'state':{selectedValues:['USA']}
});    

var statePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'State',
        'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false,
            'allowNone': false
        }
    },
    'state':{selectedValues:['New York']}
});

var cityPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control3',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'City',
        'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false,
            'allowNone': false
        },
    'state':{selectedValues:['New York City']}
    }
});

// Define a Bar Chart
var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    'options': {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 400,
        'legend': 'none',
        'vAxis':{minValue:0},
        'hAxis':{title:''},
    },
    // Instruct the chart to show Value1, Value2, and Sum from data1
    'view': {
        'columns': [1,3,4,5]
    }
});

// Define a Table
var tableChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
        'width': '400px'
    },
    // Instruct the table to show City, Addr, Owner1, and Owner2 from data2
    'view': {
        'columns': [1,2]
    }
});    

// Create a dashboard
dashone = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard1'));
dashtwo = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard2'));

// Establish bindings; cityPicker will drive both charts
dashone.bind(countryPicker, statePicker);
dashone.bind(statePicker,cityPicker);
dashone.bind(cityPicker,barChart);

dashtwo.bind(cityPicker,tableChart);

// Draw the entire dashboard.
dashone.draw(data1);
dashtwo.draw(data2);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

As you can see in the Fiddle, the code is in working order, and it produces the bar chart exactly as I'd expect. The problem is the table - I want to bind the `City` category filter with the table chart and draw it with `Data2`.

For example: when `USA` and `New York` are selected as the country and state, the invisible `City` control should autoselect `New York City`, and the column chart should populate from `Data1` with all matches for `New York City` found in the `Data1` column titled `City`. This part is working perfectly.

Then I want the table to populate *from `Data2`* with all matches for `New York City` found in the `Data2` column titled `City`, and put Columns 1 and 2 from those matching `Data2` rows in the table.

The result should be a table with three rows and two columns, and look like this:

Addr --- 123 Broadway

Owner1 --- John

Owner2 --- Smith

Yet while the second dashboard seems to have no problems grabbing the value from the `City` control in the first dash - an issue I figured might be problematic - the table populates without error, *but from `Data1`*:

New York --- New York City

Even though I'm explicitly instructing Charts to draw the table in a separate dashboard, with a draw command using `Data2`...yet when the code runs, the table is drawn with `Data1` data?

I'm stumped. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind the same control in different Dashboards.  Bind your controls to the BarChart, and create a "ready" event handler for the BarChart that gets the state of the `cityPicker` control, filters the Table's data based on the control state, and draws the Table with the filtered data.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(barChart, 'ready', function () {
    var city = cityPicker.getState().selectedValues[0];
    var rows = data2.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, value: city}]);
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data2);
    view.setRows(rows);
    tableChart.setDataTable(view);
    tableChart.draw();
});
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/GzfB8/

Note that this will require further refinement if you have any states with more than one city.